# How to find the existence of specific name between one other name in dataframe?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data frame and as an example you can see part of it below:

```
name=c("ENS1","ENS1","ENS1", "ENS2", "ENS2", "ENS2","ENS2", "ENS2", "ENS2")
position=c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2")
dif=c("mir1","ENS1","ENS1", "ENS2", "mir4", "mir2","mir3", "ENS2", "mir1")
data=data.frame(name,position,dif)
```

Now, I want to know is there any `mir` between two same `ENS` or not and also I want to know for which `ENS` I have `mir` before it?

So I need some codes to get result like this:

```
ENS1  FALSE (No mir in between)

ENS2  TRUE (mir in between)
```

Comment: Do you need to group by `position`?

Comment: No need to group, the order is the same to last column.

Comment: You have changed both your data and expected result entirely. Not to mention that the output now is completely unclear. My code still works with this data as per your previous desired output.

Comment: your right I have changed the question again... But really i get incorrect answer in bigger data...

Comment: for example when I have data like this in dif column : "mir1", "mir2","mir1","ENS3","ENS3", I get TRUE with that code, but as you can see the result have to be FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indx <- unique(grep("ENS", dif, value = TRUE))

result=sapply(indx, function(x) diff((which(x == data$dif))) > 1)

result_final <- vector(mode="list", length=length(result))

for(i in 1: length(result_final))

{

mydata <- result[[i]]

mydata <- sort(mydata,decreasing = TRUE)

names <- names(result[i])

if (mydata == "TRUE") {

```
result_final[[i]] <- c(names, "both")
```

} else {

```
result_final[[i]] <- c(names, "proximal")
```

}

}

result_final <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,result_final))